# Как собрать html с рисунками в один файл?

Tags: c++, вывод, wxwidgets

У меня есть программа с использованием wxWidgets, часть результатов которой выводится в виде HTML с рисунками через соответствующий виджет.
Читать с экрана здорово и красиво, но хотелось бы еще и написать сохранение результатов. Конечно, можно написать печать — но это оказывается очень долгой и сложной процедурой.

Так что мне хотелось бы иметь возвожность сохранения этого html в файл, благо что никаких скриптов там просто нет. Вопрос о том, в какой и как.

Я задумывался было об mhtml и fb2. Но если второй руками написать еще как-то можно довольно просто, то первый, который вроде бы представляет собой multipart mime, я не очень представляю как сделать самостоятельно. Мне казалось, что может помочь cURL, но никакого примера не нашел.
К тому же эти форматы не слишком распространены, и непонятно, будут ли они удобны пользвателям (это результаты научных расчетов с таблицами графиками).

Что бы вы могли посоветовать? Что-то более-менее распространенное и несложное в написании, а главное - в воспроизведении у другого пользователя без особых дополнительных программ, но обязательно с какими-то если не готовыми примерами, то хотя бы со ссылками на них.

Comment: Запихать картинки в data URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs

Comment: возможно подойдет `base64` на странице `html`, был бы это просто `js` реализацию просто было бы сделать, на плюсах, чуть сложнее будет, но через регулярки можно решить.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Запихать в base64 не вопрос, но вот составить потом multipart из кусочков? Или я что-то не так понял? Какой-то живой пример можете показать?

Comment: а зачем Вам multipart?

Comment: @DaniilLoban В base64 записать проблем нет. А как это правильно в страницу записать? Вместо `<img` или как?

Comment: @DaniilLoban Я нашел, что mhtml - это multipart/mime контейнер.

Comment: Пишется `<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0K` и так далее... Вот гляньте ответ с [красной точкой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/6750422)  Т.е. если у Вас плюсы, то готовите base64 и распихиваете по src

Comment: Посмотреля я `mht` формат, такой можно легко сгенерировать на чем угодно, это просто полотно текста. Так что если рассматриваете `mhtml` думаю подойдет (вроде как одно и то же)`Этот формат иногда именуется MHT, поскольку расширение .mht присваивается по умолчанию файлам, созданным программами Microsoft Word, Internet Explorer или Opera` — из википедии

Comment: @DaniilLoban Спасибо, попробую этот вариант...

Comment: @Mikhailo может пригодиться [спецификация](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557)

Comment: @DaniilLoban Пока у меня возникли проблемы с wxWidgets, так что пока не добрался...

Comment: я с ними как-то пытался работать, но они у меня так и не взлетели почему-то)

Comment: @DaniilLoban Спасибо, работает!